# Stop WebStorm showing static class properties as 'Unused field'

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

Whenever I define a static class property WebStorm tells me it's an 'unused property', which isn't true for things like prop types. For some reason this only happens in my personal projects, at work it isn't an issue.

How do I stop WebStorm showing the following two static methods as unused properties without disabling the unused property inspection on all properties?

```
class TestScreen extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onLeftButtonPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Test Title'
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`propTypes`: please vote for [WEB-25093](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25093)

`navigationOptions`: [WEB-26298](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26298)